# How would I change the test to support both Chrome and IE for this protractor test?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am writing integration tests for protractor. I have noticed that Internet Explorer does not support certain commands that Chrome supports. Let's take an example in the following test:

```
  it('should render the correct deadOffLead dialog', function () {
        // open dialog
        var deadOffLeadButton = element(by.id('deadOffLeadButton'));
        deadOffLeadButton.click();
        expect(element(by.id('deadOffLeadOkButton')).isPresent()).toBe(true);

        // enter notes
        element(by.model('modalData.notes')).sendKeys(newNoteText);

        // dead off lead click
        var deadOffLeadOkButton = element(by.id('deadOffLeadOkButton'));
        deadOffLeadOkButton.click();
        browser.sleep(1000);

        // navigate to Notes tab
        var notesTab = element(by.linkText('Notes'));
        notesTab.click();
        expect(element(by.id('addNoteTop')).isPresent()).toBe(true);

        // refresh page at this point
        browser.refresh();

        // check note is preset
        element(by.repeater('note in data.notes').row(0).column('note.text')).getText().then(function (text) {
            expect(text).toBe(newNoteText);
        });
    });
```

When run against Internet Explorer, I receive the following error:

TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'refresh'

This most probably means that **browser.refresh();** is not supported by the Internet Explorer driver. What is the Internet Explorer equivalent for this command and how would I change the test to support both Chrome and IE for this protractor test?

Comment: What about `browser.driver.refresh()`?

Comment: Unfortunately above doesn't work. I've investigated the issue a little on my own, looking for workarounds. Geting the current url and forcing browser to go to it (as a false refresh) seems to be affected by the same issue. I settled with using a webpage navigation to change pages back and forth (now I feel dirty). It is possible that this error can be avoided by simply not ignoring protected mode settings (IE workaround: http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html) - will investigate it further later.